# Understanding Dates in MySql

Tags: mysql

I seem to be missing something fundamental.  I an a new refugee from an old esoteric French database system (4D) and Im new to mySQL.

Given The following DB:

```
CREATE  TABLE `stuff` (
  `ID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `Product` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `Sell_by` DATE NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`) );


INSERT INTO `Stuff` (`Product`, `Sell_by`) VALUES ('Milk', '2013-05-16');
INSERT INTO `Stuff` (`Product`, `Sell_by`) VALUES ('Cheese', '2013-06-15');
INSERT INTO `Stuff` (`Product`, `Sell_by`) VALUES ('Yogurt', '2013-07-02');
INSERT INTO `Stuff` (`Product`, `Sell_by`) VALUES ('Bread', '2013-08-17');
INSERT INTO `Stuff` (`Product`, `Sell_by`) VALUES ('Twinkies', '2099-04-16');
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3ef48e/1

Why doesn't this return Milk Cheese and Yogurt?  It returns nothing.

```
SELECT * FROM  Stuff Where Sell_by <= 2013-07-04;
```

But this returns everything?

```
SELECT * FROM  Stuff Where Sell_by >= 2013-07-04;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your query is not actually checking for a date, but a numeric expression ( 2013 - 7  - 4 ).

Put the date expression in single quotes ('2013-07-14') and you should be fine.

Comment: ooh. Interesting.  In line math functions.   I should have left that archaic database system sooner.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I think you are missing quotes; try this:

```
SELECT * FROM  Stuff Where Sell_by <= '2013-07-04';
```

Answer (score 3):

Use quotes around date like:

```
SELECT * FROM  Stuff Where Sell_by <= '2013-07-04';
```